# Tool / program / service that helps filter email addresses

Tags: email, email-filter

I collected a bunch of email addresses, but they are not verified.

I now want to manually sort out obvious false ones (like test@test.com).

I'm looking for a tool / program / service that **helps** me (I'm aware that this can still be a lot of manual work).

Is there a tool that let me prefilter against i.e. all addresses that contains "asdf" or "test". (Tried open office calc, but not happy with the UI so far)

Answer (score 1):

That's completely the wrong way to verify email addresses. asdf@theirdomain.com and test@theirdomain.com could be valid email addresses.  You can't use any method to determine that someone will get your email, without sending an email.

Fortunately, there's a much better way.  You send them a single email with a unique link to click on (as soon as possible after acquiring the address, so they remember you).  If they click the link you have a valid email address, and you can send them mail, providing you honor unsubscribe requests.

If they don't click on that link, then *you do not have permission to send them mail*.  If you send them mail anyway, then you are sending **SPAM**, and eventually a lot of your mail will get blocked.

See also this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366734/how-check-if-an-email-address-is-fake

For general advice on running a mailing list have a look at this:

- http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/newsletter.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm considering verifying the email in the future. However, for now I looking for an tool, that helps me doing manual sorting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, and thanks for the links. Again, I'm aware, that there is no way to verify them 100% without sending them. I just filter out obviously false ones.

Comment: honestly; don't do it.  False confidence is worse than none.  Even email addresses that you think are obviously false might not be.  Even [Test.com, Inc.](http://test.com) use email.  And once you've guessed your "not-fake" addresses, you've still got to verify them anyway, if you want to send email to them.  So why bother?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe editors such as vim and emacs can help you.

For example, in vim you can use `/asdf` to find all "asdf" substring in a document, then you can use `dd` to delete the whole line if the e-mail addresses are stored separated in lines.

Regular expressions are also available in vim, for example you may use `/.*asdf.*@.*\n//gc` if you want to delete all ".*asdf.*@.*" pattern stuff with a confirmation or `/.*asdf.*@.*\n//g` to do this without that.

Answer (score 0):

My former employers, [DeskShare](http://www.deskshare.com), have a product called Smart Email Verifier that's better than a manual editor. Disclaimer: I have no current business relationship with DeskShare and will receive no compensation should you purchase SEV.